Using Subselects in HQL
Is it possible to use nested subselects in hql?
I am working on a generic system to retrieve data from a database in order to populate (html) tables. This system can run aggregations and knows how to group data. I recently noticed that sometimes the sums did not match the expected value.
Further investigation revealed a rather obvious bug: In distinct queries, the values where added up without taking the reduced number of results by the distinct query into account.
I have a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8cN6xN8jBEcepdFNuaJv6v/1
We have two tables. We do only display data from one table, but need to join another table (this is a super simplified version of a big and ugly real world example).
There are 5 Queries:

All the data, just as plain select
The same data, but distinct (no change in results)
All the columns from my root_entity, selected distinct: only one result. This is the relevant data which I want to work on. The user expect this to be the data to have the aggregations applied on.
The query as it is run today: The sum does not take the distinct-query into account, so the numeric_value is added twice.
The query I want to run.

Is there a way to run a query like this in hql? When I try to run this query, there is always an error at the beginning of the inner subselect.
Kind regards!
